# How to modify another UWP app's context menu?

Tags: visual-c++, uwp, windows-10-universal

I want to add a new item to **another UWP app**'s context menu(right-click menu), given its process name. The most close documentation I got is [Create and consume an app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service). But it doesn't meet my need.

For win32 app, I know the procedure is as following ([Modify right-click context menu in standard controls](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?776385-RESOLVED-Modify-right-click-context-menu-in-standard-controls)):

1. Get the handle of the main window of that process.
2. Add a message loop processing procedure to it and monitor WM_ContextMenu message
3. Get the handle of the context menu, add a new menu item.

But I don't know how to do for UWP apps. Can you give me some clue?

Comment: UWP apps are sandboxed.

Comment: So it is impossible to modify the behavior of a closed-source UWP app?

Comment: This is impossible. Can you enter a suggestion and provide more information on your scenario over at [Windows Platform UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform)?